# How to present a standard UIViewController modally

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a standard `ViewController` modally, but can't figure out how to do it.  The view controller will have buttons which will ultimately trigger the dismissing actions, so I don't need to wrap it in a `NavigationController`.  Also, I'm doing all of this programmatically, without .xibs.

Here's the code I'm using:

```m
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"view did appear within rootviewcontroller");
    WelcomeViewController *welcome = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:welcome animated:true];
    [welcome release];
}
```

The problem is that I haven't set the `WelcomeViewController's` view, so loadView is not getting run, which means no content is being drawn to the screen.

Every example I find, including Apple's, uses either a .xib to initialize the ViewController, a NavigationController that adds a RootViewController, or both. My understanding is that loadView is called automatically for you in both of these scenarios.
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW3

Where do I configure my `WelcomeViewController's` view?  Right there after the alloc/init?  Inside `WelcomeViewController's` init method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where do I configure my WelcomeViewController's view?

Override the `loadView` method in your subclass.  See [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH101-SW35).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that doesn't actually answer my question.  I am already overriding loadView, but it's not getting called.  loadView should never be called directly, and only gets called "when the view property is requested but is currently nil."  So my actual question is, where/how do I request the view property?

Comment: You don't.  When a view controller is presented, UIKit requests the view.  If it doesn't exist yet, your `loadView` gets called.

Comment: Sheesh...I must have screwed something up and confused the code during my testing of different solutions.  If I just present it modally and do nothing else, I'm now seeing loadView called.  So then right there in loadView is where I'd alloc/init a generic UIView, and set it to self.view, correct?

Comment: Yep, that's right.  You can use any scalable view you like, but a generic `UIView` is the most common.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example of how you can go about it without using NIBs:

In your AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, you create an instance of your custom view controller and add it as a subview of window (pretty standard).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    RootViewController *vc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self.window addSubview:vc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

When creating the `vc` instance, you use the designated initialiser which will be called on the new instance of the view controller. You don't specify any nibs because you will do your custom initialisation inside the method:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [label setNumberOfLines:2];
        [label setText:@"This is the vc view with an\norange background and a label"];
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
        [self.view addSubview:label];
        [label release];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Sorry about code formatting. There's something with posting from iPad that ends up ignoring my line breaks??

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Not sure if I was clear, (I'll go back and edit my question) but I'm doing everything programmatically, without .xib's.  Therefore, I need to know where to set VC.view since I don't have the loading of a nib or the adding to a navigation controllers rootViewController property to do this for me automatically.  If I set the view right after I alloc/init, I can get a modal to pop up but loadView doesn't get called.

Comment: @djibouti33 Code edited with a simple example. See if it makes sense now.

Comment: thanks Rog.  I plugged your code into mine, and RootVC's loadView ends up getting called repeatedly.  I actually solved the problem using Jim's suggestion.  I just present the WelcomeViewController, and loadView is called automatically.  Then, inside loadView, I create a generic UIView and assign self.view to that.  That's working perfectly, and loadView only gets called once.  Also, since I'm not using .xibs, I can just call init instead of calling initWithNibName:bundle: with nil.  Thanks for your help!